# How to update an integer using JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sql-update

I'm trying to update a table, trying to input a `integer` (age).

First I had the same problem with `insert`, them, after some answers here, I could manage to work properly, but, using the same solution on a `update` command, doesn't work.

Here's the solution for `insert`:

```
PreparedStatement pst = conecta.conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO cad_pessoa(cad_cpf,cad_nome, cad_idade, cad_apelido, cad_data) values (?,?,?,?,?)");

pst.setString(1, jFormattedTextFieldCPF.getText()); //pega o texto insirido e armazena no banco de dados
pst.setString(2, jTextFieldNOME.getText()); //pega o texto insirido e armazena no banco de dados
int n1 = Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldIDADE.getText());
pst.setInt(3, n1); //pega o texto insirido e armazena no banco de dados
pst.setString(4, jTextFieldAPELIDO.getText());//pega o texto insirido e armazena no banco de dados
SimpleDateFormat formatter  = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy");
java.util.Date utilDate = null;

try {
    utilDate = formatter.parse(jFormattedTextFieldDATA.getText());
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Pessoa3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
pst.setDate(5, sqlDate);
pst.executeUpdate();
```

The problem with the `update` is: Column is in type Integer but expression is of type character varying.

Here's the code for `update`:

```java
PreparedStatement pst = conecta.conn.prepareStatement("update cad_pessoa set cad_nome= ?, cad_idade=?, cad_apelido= ? where cad_cpf= ?");

pst.setString(1, jTextFieldNOME.getText()); //pega o texto insirido e armazena no banco de dados
pst.setString(2, jTextFieldIDADE.getText()); //pega o texto insirido e armazena no banco de dados
int n1 = Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldIDADE.getText()); //string to int
pst.setInt(3, n1); //pega o texto insirido e armazena no banco de dados
pst.setString(4, jFormattedTextFieldCPF.getText()); //pega o texto insirido e armazena no banco de dados

pst.executeUpdate(); //executa o SQL
pst.execute();
```

So, how can I make this work?

Comment: `set cad_nome= ?, cad_idade=?, cad_apelido= ? where cad_cpf= ?`  and `pst.setInt(3, n1);` - `cad_idade` is at index 2, not 3.

Comment: silly mistake, thank you very much, now it is working

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few suggestions:

- It's bad when I see Swing and database code intermingled.  Keep them strictly separate.  Your app should be constructed in layers.
- I wouldn't persist age, because it changes every day.  I'd persist birthday and calculate age when I needed it.
- You don't say which statement gives you the error.  I assume it's here:

  ```
   int n1 = Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldIDADE.getText()); //string to int
   pst.setInt(3, n1); //pega o texto insirido e armazena no banco de dados
  ```

The variable `cad_apeli` is the fourth argument in your INSERT, but it's the third in your UPDATE.  I'm guessing that you've got some confusion about columns.